# Bins with two characteristics matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram, bins, discretization

I have data stored for `N=1000` elements (air conditioners, ACs).

Each element has a number of characteristics, mainly their temperature, and the binary state of the ON/OFF switch. All this data is already generated and stored in the following way:

- Each AC is an entry in a `cell` array.
- Each AC has a **different** deadband temperature `limits_deadband` (this is an entry of the upper `cell` array).
- For the temperature I have another `cell` array with a vector from a simulation, of dimension `8641x1`.
- For the ON/OFF binary state I have another `cell` array with a vector from a simulation, of dimension `8641x1`.

What I would like to generate is the following:

- Divide `limits_deadband` for each AC into `N/2` bins (say `20` for example).
- Then use `N` to represent the temperature **and** the ON/OFF status.
- Plot the number of ACs in each bin and ON/OFF status over the measured `8641` data points.

---

What I have so far:

```
load(['my_data.mat']);

%% 1) Divide the deadband of each EWH into N_bin bins
%
% number of bins
N_bin = 20;

limits_deadband = cell(1,1000);
ON_OFF_state = cell(1,1000);
for ii = 1:1000
    % get the limits for the 20 bins of the deadband
    limits_deadband{ii} = linspace(0,Params.T_dead(:,:,ii),N_bin + 1);
    % add the temperature set-point
    limits_deadband{ii} = limits_deadband{ii} + Params.T_set(:,:,ii);

    % ON/OFF state of the internal switch for an entire day
    ON_OFF_state{ii} = Results_comparison.urec(1,:,ii);
end
```

`limits_deadband` are the **edges** of the bins in which I would like to store the temperatures. 
`ON_OFF_state` gives the state.

Any ideas on how to plot this properly? I thought using [`histogram`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histogram.html), but not sure on how to do this.

Comment: Output should roughly look like this for each individual AC? `hist(rand(30,2));legend({'on','off'});xlabel('temperature');`

Comment: @Daniel well, that's another question. I could either do it as you suggest, generating such a plot as you suggested every 30 minutes/1 hour (basically sampling the `8641` points of the simulation), OR doing a 3D plot out of it (temp vs. ON/OFF status vs. time)

Comment: @Daniel major issue for me is also the **classification** of the data into the bin edges and ON/OFF states